# Recognizing facial expressions

Tags: perception, emotion, reference-request

I seem to recall reading an article some number of years ago on a study or set of studies that examined the impact that a story has on the interpretation of facial expressions.

Something along the line of where different participants are told different stories about an event and then shown a picture of a facial expression and asked to describe what the person in the picture is feeling.  The study, as I vaguely recall it, examined how the interpretation of the facial expression changed based on the different stories given.

Does this ring a bell?  My Google searches are turning up related topics but not this specifically.  I am not especially knowledgeable of the subject matter, which is hindering my ability to form a useful search, and I'd like to read more about it.

If there is a name for this effect, assuming there is such an effect, it would help me considerably in finding information on it.

I would very much appreciate your consideration and suggestions.  Thank you.

Comment: Something simular to this: "Mood effects on emotion recognition" https://www.researchgate.net/publication/225559951_Mood_effects_on_emotion_recognition ?